# Identified latent class from experiment data

Tags: random-allocation, latent-class

I have a large data set generated by a random experiment conducted by an online retail company. The treatment is changing the position of the text review. Specifically, in the control (default) group, the position of the text review is in position X of the webpage and in the treatment group, the position of the text review is in position Y of the webpage. The data recorded the account of each customer. The experiment lasted for Z months, which means during the experiment, you could see the same customer visit the website for multiple times and may make purchase for multiple times. During the experiment, each customer will be randomly assigned to one of the group (control or treatment). This means if the first time a customer is assigned to the treatment group, then throughout the Z months, every time when this customer visit this website, he is always assigned to the treatment group.

Here I my two questions:

(1) I am suspecting that within the customer population, there will be intrinsically 2 types of the customers: (a) patient customer (b) impatient customer. I suspect that the impatient customer, if put in the treatment group, will ignore the review but the patient customer, no matter he is assigned to the treatment or control group, there is no big difference for his behavior related to the text review. **My question** is that how to identify these 2 types of customers from the data? The data set records 3 variables which I think related to my question (i) duration of each session (time in seconds between a customer open this website and close this website); (ii) number of page viewed by each customer during each session; (iii) number of products viewed by each customer during each session.

(2) I am suspecting that the product type will also affect the customers' behavior. The data set does record the product category purchased and viewed by each customer. To answer this question, the idea situation would be, I have 2 types of product, and I randomly assign customers to these 2 types, and see how much time did they spend on reading the review. However, it is not the setting in this experiment.

I think the goal of this experiment is trying to see how this treatment (different position of the text review) will affect the revenue (This is something I can run a simple regression to check). I just want to fully utilize this data set to address more questions (the two I proposed here). But I am not sure what is the right methodology to use.